# jQuery UI Dialog Close button doesn't show up with local jQuery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is going to sound like a seriously stupid question.  I have a very super simple page that I created that currently just displays a jQuery modal Dialog box.  If, when I link to the jquery files, I just link to `http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css` for example, everything works just fine.  When I download those files and link to the local directory, almost everything works fine, but the close button in the top of the dialog doesn't show up.  The box is there, and it's clickable, but the `X` isn't there.  Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Share your code in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the CSS there are references to images like:

```
background-image: url(images/ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x240.png);
```

Did you also download the images and placed them in the correct directory?

just get the whole package of jQueryUI http://jqueryui.com/download/

Comment: That would definitely be my problem.  I'll do that right now.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the images stored locally as well?  You should probably download the **whole** jQuery UI package from here http://jqueryui.com/ instead of trying to find the individual files from the CDN.